# Array repete simultaneamente no json

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

Estou a tentar fazer um calendário onde vou buscar a informação num pedido rest em angularjs. O que pretendo criar um calendário onde dê para registar os seus eventos. Com o atributo data do json ele insira esse evento e regista uma icon nesse dia.

O meu erro é como podem ver na imagem ele vai buscar um array e insere nos campos todos e não só no dia que foi registado no json. A minha função repete 42 vezes que é o número dos quadrados do calendário.
Alguém sabe onde está o erro na minha abordagem é que não estou a perceber.

Imagem

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Json

```
{"data":[
    {"title":"John", 
     "start":"2016-10-22"
    }, {
     "title":"João", 
     "start":"2016-10-25"
    }
]}
```

controller

```
$scope.setDayContent = function(date) {

    return $http ({
        method : "GET",
        url : "app/components/home/controller/test_calendar.json"
      }).then(function mySucces(response) {
            console.log(response.data.data[1]);
        }, function myError(response) {
          $scope.valor = response.statusText;
      });
```

html

```
    <calendar-md flex layout layout-fill
          calendar-direction="direction"
          on-prev-month="prevMonth"
          on-next-month="nextMonth"
          on-day-click="dayClick"
          ng-model='selectedDate'
          week-starts-on="firstDayOfWeek"
          tooltips="tooltips"
          day-format="dayFormat"
          day-content="setDayContent"
          ></calendar-md>
```

version 2:

```
 $scope.loadData = function(){

      return $http ({
        method : "GET",
        url : "app/components/home/controller/test_calendar.json"
      }).then(function mySucces(response) {
           $scope.jsonData = response.data.data;
        }, function myError(response) {
          $scope.valor = response.statusText;
      }); 
    }


    $scope.setDayContent = function(date, content) {


//check if $scope.jsonData contains date parameter
// return title

    };
```

Comment: O teu problema parece-me que cada dia está a chamar um pedido de ajax. Se vires na consola tens provavelmente 42 chamadas ajax, em vêz de uma só. Não conheço a API do angular para poder ajudar, mas se ninguém responder, dou uma olhada no fim de semana. `+1`

Comment: eu preciso de criar um atributo lógico para que ele perceba que aquela data especifica só pode mostrar 1 vez e não as 42 vezes. Acho que é isto, Corrige-me se tiver errado

Answer (score 0):

Já entendi o ponto que está gerando esse loop de busca.

O seu `setDayContent` é chamado pelo componente para você poder informar o conteúdo do dia, porém você não está tratando os parâmetros passados pelo componente e buscando do dia que ele pediu, mas retornando todo o calendário.

Sugestão:
Tratar o seu `setDayContent` para buscar na requisição apenas o dia que ele pediu, que está nos parâmetros que o componente te envia.

Ou, carregar os eventos antes de carregar o componente e no seu `setDayContent` você procura nesse array ou objeto de eventos já carregados pela data que ele te requisitou via parâmetro.

E é bom você voltar lá na página do componente que você está usando e ler melhor a documentação dele.

---

### UPDATE

Então cara, eu dei uma olhada na [documentação](https://angular-material-calendar.bradb.net).

É isso mesmo, seu erro é não filtrar a data que o componente pediu.
O componente te da a opção de responder com html, ou com uma promise.

Comment: o problema é que não há documentação para esta parte. 
Mas eu criei agora uma função antes do setdaycontent com o pedido get ao json e dentro do setdaycontent vou tentar buscar apenas a data

Comment: vou editar o meu código e diz me se estou a ir pelo um bom caminho
eu não estou a perceber.

Comment: Giovane, coloca por favor uma sugestão de como o código deveria ser para resolver o problema. @JoseCerejo por favor não mudes a pergunta para adaptar às respostas que vão surgindo. Senão fica a pergunta e a resposta sem sentido.

Comment: @Sergio não vou por código pq nunca trabalhei com esse componente, e a solução é simples. O seu `setDayContent` tem que responder a data que o componente pede, pronto, faça com que responda.